# How to create a shadow for a rectangle in android using Paint object's setShadowLayer method?

Tags: android, draw, paint, shadow, drawrectangle

```
        Paint fillpaint = new Paint(this.getPaint());
        fillpaint.setColor(fillColor);

        Paint strokepaint = new Paint(fillpaint);
        strokepaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        strokepaint.setStrokeWidth(borderWidth);
        strokepaint.setColor(borderColor);
```

I am creating a rectangle using two paint objects as shown above(one for fill and one for stroke).  I need to create a shadow for this rectangle and the shadow's blur radius, color, offsets for x and y should be customizable.
Paint object has setShadowLayer method using which I can create a shadow for a paint object. 
The problem is to find out how to use the setShadowLayer method to get a shadow for the rectangle I am creating.  Should I invoke setShadowLayer on fillpaint or strokepaint?  I invoked setClipChildren(false) on the target's parent view and I invoked setShadowLayer on strokepaint  but its not rendering correctly. I need a simple example that uses setShadowLayer on paint and I can apply that to my code.